# DBSCAN kdist-Plot multiple valleys

Tags: python, parameters, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am using Sander et al. 1998 to determine MinPts and epsilon to use DBSCAN on my dataset.
As Sanders et all suggests minpts=dim*2-1=k (in my case 9 dimensions --> minpts=k=17).
In the paper one should chose the "first valley". I can see two valleys but which one is the first one? And what value would you chose for epsilon?
[kdistplot_with_duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2xU1.jpg)

Since Sanders also suggests that this method should be only used if there are no duplicates, one without them: (though I think in this case it should not matter)
[kdistplot_without_duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhBVP.jpg).
Which valley should be considered the "first" one?

Code used:

```
ns = 17
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=ns, metric='euclidean').fit(data)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(data)
distanceDec = sorted(distances[:,ns-1], reverse=True)
plt.plot(list(range(1,683+1)), distanceDec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates there may be hierarchies of clusters, or clusters with varying density.

In such cases, a *single* threshold on DBSCAN will not be enough. You can try clustering twice, **with two different thresholds**. Or you use a hierarchical version such as OPTICS and HDBSCAN. Recently, people have been quite happy with HDBSCAN, I have had better results with OPTICS (and I believe there is a good reason *why*, namely that I want border points to be part of the cluster)

Answer (score 0):

It is the valley on the left (the smallest values of epsilon): with this value, all the points on the left are unclustered (considered as noise) and all the points on the right will be clustered.

You can read the original [DBSCAN paper](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/KDD/1996/KDD96-037.pdf) and in particular see Figure 4 to better understand the rationale.

Comment: Yes it is said that is considered as noise. It should still be able end up in a cluster if it is in the neighborhood of a core point.